# How to loop through dictionary values in ansible

Tags: json, dictionary, ansible, keyvaluepair

I am trying to loop through the dictionary of "key": & "Value". I am not getting proper results. I want to print the value of certain Key from a dictionary.

Here is my code:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  strategy: free
  tasks:
  - include_vars: roles/oracle/vars/install_vars.yaml
    vars:
     var_list:
        - script_name

  - set_fact:
      ORACLE_HOMES_DIR: "/u01/app/oracle/product"
      DB_HOME: "{{ ORACLE_HOMES_DIR }}/{{ ORACLE_VERSION }}/dbinst_1"

  - name: Copy script to host
    copy:
      src: "{{ playbook_dir }}/{{ script_name }}"
      dest: "/tmp/"
      owner: "{{ USER_ORACLE }}"
      group: "{{ GROUP_ORACLE }}"
      mode: 0755

  - name: Verify if the DB is open READ WRITE (or) not
    become_user: "{{ USER_ORACLE }}"
    environment:
      ORACLE_SID: "{{ sid }}"
      ORACLE_HOME: "{{ ORACLE_HOME }}"
    shell: "echo \"set pagesize 0\n select trim(open_mode) from v\\$database;\" | {{ORACLE_HOME}}/bin/sqlplus -S / as sysdba"
    with_items: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['sid_list'] }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: sid
    register: om

  - name: Get the OM output
    debug:
     msg: "om Results {{ item.0.sid }} is {{ item.1.value }}"
    with_dict: "{{ om.results }}"
    when: ("'sid' in item.key" and "'stdout' in item.key")
```

I am trying to print all the value for keys "sid" & "stdout" here, below is the dictionary output. So i can use loop condition to loop through running SQL queries for all SID's which are in "READ WRITE" mode.

```
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': True, 'key': '_ansible_parsed'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results _ansible_parsed is True"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': [], 'key': 'stderr_lines'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results stderr_lines is []"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': True, 'key': '_ansible_item_result'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results _ansible_item_result is True"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': u'2019-05-17 14:15:02.065806', 'key': u'end'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results end is 2019-05-17 14:15:02.065806"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': False, 'key': '_ansible_no_log'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results _ansible_no_log is False"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': u'READ WRITE', 'key': u'stdout'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results stdout is READ WRITE"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': u'echo "set pagesize 0\nselect trim(open_mode) from v\\$database;" | /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbinst_1/bin/sqlplus -S / as sysdba', 'key': u'cmd'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results cmd is echo \"set pagesize 0\nselect trim(open_mode) from v\\$database;\" | /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbinst_1/bin/sqlplus -S / as sysdba"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': 0, 'key': u'rc'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results rc is 0"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': {u'module_args': {u'warn': True, u'executable': None, u'_uses_shell': True, u'_raw_params': u'echo "set pagesize 0\nselect trim(open_mode) from v\\$database;" | /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbinst_1/bin/sqlplus -S / as sysdba', u'removes': None, u'argv': None, u'creates': None, u'chdir': None, u'stdin': None}}, 'key': u'invocation'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results invocation is {u'module_args': {u'warn': True, u'executable': None, u'_uses_shell': True, u'_raw_params': u'echo \"set pagesize 0\\nselect trim(open_mode) from v\\\\$database;\" | /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbinst_1/bin/sqlplus -S / as sysdba', u'removes': None, u'argv': None, u'creates': None, u'chdir': None, u'stdin': None}}"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': False, 'key': 'failed'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results failed is False"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': u'0:00:00.072933', 'key': u'delta'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results delta is 0:00:00.072933"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': u'', 'key': u'stderr'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results stderr is "
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': True, 'key': u'changed'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results changed is True"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': u'abhitest1', 'key': u'sid'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results sid is abhitest1"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': [u'READ WRITE'], 'key': u'stdout_lines'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results stdout_lines is [u'READ WRITE']"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': u'2019-05-17 14:15:01.992873', 'key': u'start'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results start is 2019-05-17 14:15:01.992873"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': None, 'key': '_ansible_ignore_errors'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results _ansible_ignore_errors is "
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': u'abhitest1', 'key': u'_ansible_item_label'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results _ansible_item_label is abhitest1"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': True, 'key': '_ansible_parsed'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results _ansible_parsed is True"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': [], 'key': 'stderr_lines'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results stderr_lines is []"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': True, 'key': '_ansible_item_result'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results _ansible_item_result is True"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': u'2019-05-17 14:15:05.315947', 'key': u'end'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results end is 2019-05-17 14:15:05.315947"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': False, 'key': '_ansible_no_log'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results _ansible_no_log is False"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': u'READ WRITE', 'key': u'stdout'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results stdout is READ WRITE"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': u'echo "set pagesize 0\nselect trim(open_mode) from v\\$database;" | /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbinst_1/bin/sqlplus -S / as sysdba', 'key': u'cmd'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results cmd is echo \"set pagesize 0\nselect trim(open_mode) from v\\$database;\" | /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbinst_1/bin/sqlplus -S / as sysdba"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': 0, 'key': u'rc'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results rc is 0"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': {u'module_args': {u'warn': True, u'executable': None, u'_uses_shell': True, u'_raw_params': u'echo "set pagesize 0\nselect trim(open_mode) from v\\$database;" | /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbinst_1/bin/sqlplus -S / as sysdba', u'removes': None, u'argv': None, u'creates': None, u'chdir': None, u'stdin': None}}, 'key': u'invocation'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results invocation is {u'module_args': {u'warn': True, u'executable': None, u'_uses_shell': True, u'_raw_params': u'echo \"set pagesize 0\\nselect trim(open_mode) from v\\\\$database;\" | /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbinst_1/bin/sqlplus -S / as sysdba', u'removes': None, u'argv': None, u'creates': None, u'chdir': None, u'stdin': None}}"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': False, 'key': 'failed'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results failed is False"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': u'0:00:00.070937', 'key': u'delta'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results delta is 0:00:00.070937"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': u'', 'key': u'stderr'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results stderr is "
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': True, 'key': u'changed'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results changed is True"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': u'dw1', 'key': u'sid'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results sid is dw1"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': [u'READ WRITE'], 'key': u'stdout_lines'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results stdout_lines is [u'READ WRITE']"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': u'2019-05-17 14:15:05.245010', 'key': u'start'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results start is 2019-05-17 14:15:05.245010"
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': None, 'key': '_ansible_ignore_errors'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results _ansible_ignore_errors is "
}
ok: [dwracdb1] => (item={'value': u'dw1', 'key': u'_ansible_item_label'}) => {
    "msg": "om Results _ansible_item_label is dw1"
```

Comment: You didn't ask this, but you might find the [`args: stdin:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/shell_module.html#parameters) task parameter easier on the eyes than using that `echo "" | ` business

Comment: What's going on with your question, as you [clearly know about `selectattr()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56193188/i-see-my-ansible-playbook-never-returns-the-prompt-when-i-have-enabled-the-debu)?

Answer (score 0):

As best I can tell, you're looking for the `sid` whose `om.results[].stdout` contains `READ WRITE`? If so, `with_dict:` is for sure the wrong way to go about that since `om.results` is a **list** not a **dict**; what you want is:

```
- debug:
    msg: read write SIDs are {{ rw_sid_list }}
  vars:
    rw_sid_list: '{{ om.results
      | selectattr("stdout", "eq", "READ WRITE")
      | map(attribute="sid")
      | list }}'
```

Comment: thanks matthew. I think the way you suggested only work's best with_dict doesn't seem to work.